# eth_call vs eth_sendTransaction

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

During my development process, I've spotted differences between calling function in my contract from script and from dApp. Whole thing is done on hardhat local network.

Script call:

```
eth_call
  Contract call:       Contract#earningInfo
  From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  To:                  0x9fe46736679d2d9a65f0992f2272de9f3c7fa6e0
```

dApp call:

```
eth_sendTransaction
  Contract call:       Contract#earningInfo
  Transaction:         0xf58da19368c9aa20c9c33d4177af0efb8c08fd9bcbc59cdfd9c9abcb09742bc2
  From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  To:                  0x9fe46736679d2d9a65f0992f2272de9f3c7fa6e0
  Value:               0 ETH
  Gas used:            23242 of 23242
  Block #6:            0x4389bde0717095ed768297b51425d805d99358f985592e3027f21d9ec1585280
```

This of course has some effects on the response itself. While first call (script) is returning plain response - second call(dApp) is returning me transactionInfo, which I probably can turn into receipt adn get Event from there, but... I think, that I miss something. Contract itself is a view, without nested calls:

```
function earningInfo(address account, uint256[] calldata _nftIds) external view returns (uint256[1] memory info) {
        uint256 earned = 0;

        for (uint i = 0; i < _nftIds.length; i++) {
            Stake memory staked = vault[_nftIds[i]];
            require(staked.owner == account, "not an owner");
            uint256 stakedAt = staked.timestamp;
            earned += tokensPerDay * 1 ether * (block.timestamp - stakedAt) / 86400;
        }

        return [earned];
    }
```

Call from dApp:

```
export const stakingEarningInfoQueryForTokens = async (userAddress: string, tokenIds: number[]): Promise<any> => {
  console.log('calling earning info', userAddress, tokenIds);
  const { contract } = await getProvider(chain, address, abi);
  return contract.earningInfo(userAddress, tokenIds);
};
```

And getProvider function:

```
export const getProvider = async (chain: string, address: string, abi: string[] ) => {
  const provider = new JsonRpcProvider(rpc[chain].rpcUrl);
  const signer = await provider.getSigner();
  const contract = new Contract(address, abi, signer);

  return {
    provider,
    signer,
    contract
  };
};
```

I don't have to confirm this transaction in wallet (MetaMask).

Follow up question might be - is the only difference between **eth_call** and **eth_sendTransaction** is that the latter one is executed on the chain - therefore it cost money + different response type? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that Ive made a mistake inside ABI.
I had:

```
  "function earningInfo(address account, uint256[] _nftIds) returns (uint256[1] memory info)",
```

instead of:

```
  "function earningInfo(address account, uint256[] _nftIds) view returns (uint256[1] memory info)",
```

Missing 'view' was the key. That was valuable lesson for me, that ABI means a lot more for ethers.js then I thought. Maybe it will also help someone else.

I will update this answer if I find a good, simple and fast way to keep consistency between my contracts and ABI's in my dApp.

Thank You @Mehran Ra, @Foxxxey and @Ake for Your input.

Answer (score 0):

`eth_call`: This is a read-only operation that executes a contract function on the local node without creating a transaction on the blockchain. It is used for querying the contract state and doesn't modify anything on the blockchain. It returns the result of the function call directly as a response.

`eth_sendTransaction`: This is used to send a transaction to the Ethereum network, which can modify the contract state and interact with other contracts. When you call a contract function using eth_sendTransaction, you are creating a transaction on the blockchain, and it will be mined into a block. This operation incurs gas fees and returns a transaction receipt, which includes information about the transaction's status and gas used.

Comment: But my concern here is - why when I call it from dApp it turns into transaction, but when called from script its just a call? It looks, like it should be just a call. Right?

Comment: @Lidjan indeed, you're doing something wrong on the dApp side. What's the code that calls this function? (side note about the differences between call and sendTransaction, eth_sendTransaction expects the tx data to be signed with a private key when eth_call doesn't)

Comment: @Foxxxey Added code from dApp - its really simple, dont see any problems there :( And side note - its working fine for other calls.

Comment: @Lidjan I think you are using ethers.js? Looking at the code chunks you provided, ethers indeed should use eth_call as your contract is view. It's weird if it does an eth_sendTransaction and looks like it consumes all gas and fails since it's an invalid tx really. To troubleshoot, I'd cut out `const signer = await provider.getSigner();` and see what it does (as you don't really need the signer for eth_call).